# A question about matrix convergence.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence

Suppose there is a sequence of $k \times k$ diagonal matrix $A^t$ whose diagonal elements $a_i^t$ are all positive. $\Sigma$ is another $n \times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix. $X$ is an $k \times n$ matrix which is not row full-rank. I am consider the behavior of $\Sigma X^T (A+X \Sigma X^T)^{-1} X \Sigma$. Will this matrix converge, when all the diagonal elements of $A^t$ go to zero (but still positive)?

I find the core difficulty lies in the fact that $X \Sigma X^T$ is not full-rank. I checked numerically and it seems to hold that
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \Sigma X^T (A^t+X \Sigma X^T)^{-1} X \Sigma = \Sigma X^T Q^T
\begin{bmatrix}
        \frac{1}{\lambda_{1}} & & & & &\\
        & \ddots & & & &\\
        & & \frac{1}{\lambda_{r}} & & &\\
        & & & 0 & &\\
        & & & & \ddots & \\
        & & & & & 0
    \end{bmatrix}
Q X \Sigma,
$$
where I do eigenvalue decomposition for $X \Sigma X^T = Q^T\Lambda Q$ with $\Lambda = \text{diag}([\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_r,0,\dots,0])$. Hope some kind man can help me with this problem. Many thanks!

Comment: Note that your matrix can be written in the form
$$
\Sigma^{1/2}[Y^T(A + YY^T)^{-1}Y]\Sigma^{1/2},
$$
where $Y = X\Sigma^{1/2}$. Under certain conditions, it can be shown that $\lim_{t \to 0}[Y^T(A^t + YY^T)^{-1}Y]$ is the projection onto the row-space of $Y$ (and this fact is used in the context of [Tikhonov regularization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_regression#Tikhonov_regularization)), but I don't believe that $A^t$ having positive diagonal entries for all $t$ is a sufficient condition by itself.